# Is it possible to have a Generic for each Mapped Type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes multiple reducers and applies them all to a data structure. For example, given two people `person1` and `person2` it can use this function to normalise their data:

```
normalizeData([person1, person2], {
    byId: {
      initialValue: {} as { [id: string]: Person },
      reduce: (acc, model) => {
        acc[model["id"]] = model
        return acc
      },
    },
    list: {
      initialValue: [] as Person[],
      reduce: (acc, model) => {
        acc.push(model)
        return acc
      },
    },
  })
```

Which will return something like:

```json
{
  byId: {
    1: {
      id: 1,
      name: "John",
    },
    2: {
      id: 2,
      name: "Jane",
    },
  },
  list: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "John",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Jane",
    },
  ],
}
```

I am having trouble implementing these types in Typescript because I want each property that I pass in to use the type of `initialValue` as the type for the accumulator `acc` in the reduce callback.

Is it possible to have this sort of inferred generic type on a mapped type?

[Here is a link to the full code in a runnable example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGUEMFsFNQC4E8AO9IGdQEEBOvIkA6XWAEwFcBjeKyAG3oCNIqBrAKGTVACVzqsAMINmrNgB4AagwqwANKADyFBClUA%20UAF5QACg6hQKUgDcAlgHsKGGfTkAuZavUJ5h0FQr5YAOwR2jqCBCh5ePv4Akr5ksAAeTr4U0EywuO5GkPiETiEA2gC67gCUOloqaqocHCCgACqo8ABmlrigGDAo9PBkkAiQXI2gAAppGJa%20OqAA3h7mZE4YCLjmvgDmHr4wsIvLqxtGKFl%20CJFkAPy7K%20sekGs7oEkpaRwAvtW1AGIUvlQIVpMEJZQLgfqBoBR6P8uvBSJQaLgsJZTGlQJBJlkCEhQJYmqBev0amA6gALcxYcmIEnNH5-AGgSKgADu6IQiGB3HgJksaFw9CQHHiKFabKatP%20E0erWgDHMAC9YAARPqQCQAWUssXoin48LSAGlYEgsPEEH4yFgltc1opouZ-gwQhoDEYCZAnBqtYUMiCBAiME5ZkYjHk2EbQKs%20H6DUaMAVAx5g769Zco3qRIwWOx1ZrYNqGb57eZHbJYBpE8HVkWS-YHnaHfQQhX3kZXiUZh5agBxWBssPGnF4uGCRHs9pde1U2DQCP%20DlM4Fu9rLagIbywDCKTtgCbNVqz6v0UCmUtYdFkKc4hDUtotNrDmieURZtgYMITJbJkeGge6JRMAArWA-iIfsMD0B8xlKTAcGyJAJH7XFEEaJDIMRctt1AHs2XRHFAOAtkkOmCMFlACQqwbJ1QBbUBamiKlKToDB4AAA2IpgkDOQM21AehyTcUBCmolj318T8KOLRtTymNCfwwEhoxdYM9EsQDFH7UptC0PQgyTUAiAM1SAJ9JNQyNeMv39MykAKIgJJrOQTOo4onOmV40SwYjrNnNNv1jCz60kkJqJ9YpqiMbtezRDE4MHSzaGfcQ3yMKgPzZSCMzEdgsF0WTYyIGUUD0PQNLKfRiP7RQ6EzcQnDQjBrNsyDnLCzDdUEHEUTaa8ehVRRIBQLokH2UBYFYEl4syl8xzGqgJoJZJRM-XxpVlBUyGVfopjdBS9WK1gqEUBboEUVZYjifq4M0rRdKMUg11wSYMsS7LdsEfaqEOmZQEqp8avYZyytu4NUrEtlqqytgAHV7RJRVYCaSBITZXQIemgAfdH9D0eZrpIsK9N9B7JmBpMDKIA6nNM-sLLR8QYeveHEeRvQDsao6%20mSU6YniS6sRcitW2bfrPoJkKD0o09Wru3tvEmFbcBlPj1s2gZ3iJCBOm6fEVQ4UHPyOUh-CcUZEUlXRdPmJwACIAAZbYARmtn0tjgG3lTIZ2PENk4uNAH5YiaVZyB9O4HgAVgAZncd59bZcZfBNsZzY7IwrdAO3bYAJi9oxXYea3wAmXPjGOKJSMzp3Q-uJwHazmOPmJMkKSwHrEA3NlzGgGE4H8PoASIDXSXgTksDIYEVpwz7YBQNkyHMJomjSEb7l8ZeqGQtAkTxeypNrUA71G8bwQGtAL05DWoZJPpYC6iMsD4pZyAP8xEXj3tW%20pAtD2C1f141xkLJ-BjlSGiJg2sgSgGviiS8qxJb705Affcs0JqFTPpveAGtT78ipH0do2wMFjjbixA6LFjyljim3ZqdN2CDwVkreUSoVR6DyD7fwigE5FFTqADiftga7xCNxDyMxrJXH2BZU2Cc2wVkgk4Vmn1FC8gTnjUmaJPqsOTr4OyZAChTCURMQWRM5ZqKoMLDw0ijCPwQAmJMAjSxOCEjBSRExvQyOjHIymxhNEqMMQdIg6gMAkj0Po3wYskz3WMQdMxrYY5hSAA)

**Reproducible example**

```js
// Same type as Array.reduce callback
type ReduceCallback<Value, Output> = (
  previousValue: Output,
  currentValue: Value,
  currentIndex: number,
  array: Value[],
) => Output

// Type for sample data
type Person = {
  id: string
  name: string
  parentId?: string
  age: number
}

// Function to run multiple reducers over an array of data
// This is the function I want to type properly
export function normalizeData<Model, ReducerKeys extends string, InitialValue>(
  data: Model[],
  reducers: {
    [key in ReducerKeys]: {
      reduce?: ReduceCallback<Model, InitialValue>
      initialValue: InitialValue
    }
  },
) {
  // Get keys of reducers to split them into two data structures, 
  // one for initial values and the other for reduce callbacks
  const reducerKeys = Object.keys(reducers) as Array<keyof typeof reducers>

  // Get an object of { id: <initialValue> }
  // In this case `{ byId: {}, list, [] }`
  const initialValues = reducerKeys.reduce(
    (obj, key) => ({
      ...obj,
      [key]: reducers[key].initialValue,
    }),
    {} as { [key in ReducerKeys]: InitialValue },
  )

  // Get an array of reduce callbacks
  const reduceCallbacks = reducerKeys.map((key) => ({ key, callback: reducers[key].reduce }))

  // Reduce over the data, applying each reduceCallback to each datum
  const normalizedData = data.reduce((acc, datum, index, array) => {
    return reduceCallbacks.reduce((acc, { key, callback }) => {
      const callbackWithDefault = callback || ((id) => id)
      return {
        ...acc,
        [key]: callbackWithDefault(acc[key], datum, index, array),
      }
    }, acc)
  }, initialValues)

  return normalizedData
}

// Sample data
const parent: Person = {
  id: "001",
  name: "Dad",
  parentId: undefined,
  age: 53,
}
const son: Person = {
  id: "002",
  name: "Son",
  parentId: "001",
  age: 12,
}

// This is the test implementation.
// The types do not accept differing generic types of initialValue for each mapped type
// Whatever is listed first sets the InitialValue generic
// I want to be able to have the intialValue type for each mapped type 
// apply that same type to the `acc` value of the reduce callback.
normalizeData([parent, son], {
  byId: {
    initialValue: {} as {[key: string]: Person},
    reduce: (acc, person) => {
      acc[person.id] = person
      return acc
    },
  },
  list: {
    initialValue: [] as Person[],
    reduce: (acc, person) => {
      acc.push(person)
      return acc
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the function declaration. I think you can remove the `ReducerKeys` generic type. We can instead rename `InitialValue` to `InitialValues` to indicate that we will store an object type inside there with each key being a specific `InitialValue`.

```
export function normalizeData<Model, InitialValues>(
  data: Model[],
  reducers: {
    [K in keyof InitialValues]: {
      reduce?: ReduceCallback<Model, InitialValues[K]>
      initialValue: InitialValues[K]
    }
  },
) { /* ... */ }
```

Instead of mapping over `ReducerKeys`, we map over `InitialValues` and store the type of `initialValue` inside `InitialValues[K]`.

This already fixed the typing when calling the function.

We now get an error inside the function implementation because `RecucerKeys` does not exist anymore. Let's just replace it with `InitialValues` too.

```
const initialValues = reducerKeys.reduce(
  (obj, key) => ({
    ...obj,
    [key]: reducers[key].initialValue,
  }),
  {} as { [K in keyof InitialValues]: InitialValues[K] },
)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=40&ssc=4&pln=34&pc=3#code/PTAEGUEMFsFNQC4E8AO9IGdQEEBOvIkA6XWAEwFcBjeKyAG3oCNIqBrAKGTVACVzqsAMINmrNgB4AagwqwANKADyFBClUA%20UAF5QACg6hQKUgDcAlgHsKGGfTkAuZavUJ5h0FQr5YAOwR2jqCBCh5ePv4Akr5ksAAeTr4U0EywuO5GkPiETiEA2gC67gCUOloqaqocHCCgACqo8ABmlrigGDAo9PBkkAiQXI2gAAppGJa%20OqAA3h7mZE4YCLjmvgDmHr4wsIvLqxtGKFl%20CJFkAPy7K%20sekGs7oEkpaRwAvtW1AGIUvlQIVpMEJZQLgfqBoBR6P8uvBSJQaLgsJZTGlQJBJlkCEhQJYmqBev0amA6gALcxYcmIEnNH5-AGgSKgADu6IQiGB3HgJksaFw9CQHHiKFabKatP%20E0erWgDHMAC9YAARPqQCQAWUssXoimi5n%20DBCGA0BiMBMgTg1WsKGRBAgRGCcsyMRjyAGlQKtQGxYEhcQzfHrzAbZLAMAVHR5nbb4bBLnw7cJRCx2OrNbBtf7A8H7KG3QUNJHnass-QQk5dfrSyGMHnC%208jK8SjMPLUAOKwNnepBIvFwwSI9ntLp6qmwaAe-wcpnAs3tZbUBDeUOKFtgCbNVoTkugUzVtExUc4hDUtotNp9mieJPiDBhCZLaP910%20rC6JRMABWsD%20RC7GD0F5jKUmA4NkSASF2fqcn6gGIgWq6gO2bLojin7fmyfrTB6CygBIxaViEWj1qAtTRFSlJ0Bg8AAAZYUwSBnI6jagPQ5JuKAhSgK81F3r4D74UGVY5q%20j4Is%203YkAmJrOnolifooXalNoWh6E6UagEQmlyR%20NpRnkXbhqJYz6T6BREAJ2ZyLpXHFNZ0yvGiWBYW6E5ej6foVoJhqGZ5lm5q6BRcTaxTVEYbYdvuaJgTivYJlejDJmwt5GFQ95soBIgJTeUyweJGBEDKKB6HoillPoWFdoodBZewTiwTWBmSTGNkhQh-DNciqLHj0KqKJAKBdEg%20ygLArAkkZmViOwg6jVQ40EskvEPr40qygqZDKv0Uxmk1gjFawVCKAt0CKKssRxH1YFKVoalGKQi64JMGXXuw%20WAftVCHTMblIFVL1sDZZW3c6qV8Wy1VTWwADqeokoqsBNJAkJsroEOJaAAA%20GP6Ho8zXdhIXqbaD2TMDUaaUQB3WXpBlOGj4gw8e8OI8jegHSZSBFPifTJKdMTxJdWK2YWDZ1n1n2E0FW4EdWrV3R23iTCtuAyqx62bQM7xEhAnTdNzhKgw%20RykP4TijIikq6Gp8xOAARAADPbACMts2lscB28qZCux4xsnIxoA-LETSrOQNp3A8ACsADM7jvIbbLjL4ZtjJbzZGDboAO-bABMPtGO7Dy2%20AEz58YxxRDh2cu%20H9xOE7Odxx8xJkhSWDdYgoZsuY0AwnA-h9ACRDa6S8CclgZDAityGfbAKBsmQ5hNE0aTDfcvir1QiCND20teSGoBniNY3gv1aBkNvaDa1DJJ9LAKJtJSrFLOQh-mIiicdu31KZjLOagOvTe2tGQsn8IOVIaImB6yBKAW%20KJDyrD-nIS%20G42izXGoVc%20KDQDazPvyKkfR2jbGwTAju1EDrUR3AfKCP9ALxUhsPZWqt5RKhVHoPIft-CKCTlzNS9EA7AwskJII9lHIzA5lcfYhlzZJ0bIWQCTg2afUULyJO%20MyZok%20hw1OvhzJkECroVREwRbE0VpoqgYsPByKMM-BAEYoxCLLBxQKIEZETGtPIhMiiqbGB0eokxB0iDqAwCSPQRjfCSyjPdMxB1LENjjiFIAA)